# Add reference to a library project from an applications PCL project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have created a library project in `Xamarin.Forms` and I'm trying to consume the functionality implemented by this project from another application PCL project created in Visual Studio.

I first added the library project to the solution of my application PCL project by right clicking on the solution name and selecting `Add -> Existing Project`.

Here's how the solution structure of my solution looks like after adding the existing library project to it:

[image]

The library project added is the last one and is highlighted by the red rectangle.

I then tried to add a reference to the library project by right clicking on the `References` section of my application project and selecting `Add Reference ...`. In the dialogue open I selected the library name i.e. `Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit` and clicked ok.

[image]

After doing that I received the error:

> Unable to add a reference to project 'Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit'. The
>   targets of Portable Library project 'Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit' are
>   not the same or compatible with the targets of the current Portable
>   Library project.

I checked the targets of both the library and the application project and found out that my library project was missing the 'Windows Phone Silverlight 8` target. Unfortunately I'm unable to either remove this target from the application project or add the target to the library project.

Any ideas on how I can get around this issue?

Comment: You should be able to remove the silverlight 8 target by going to the libraries properties and removing the checkmark in the "change targets" dialog. Does it give you any error?

Comment: @Kai Brummund I already tried this. The 'change targets' dialog doesn't contain the Silverlight 8 target.

Comment: You are using VS2017, right? Silverlight has propably been removed there. You can try to edit the .csproj file of your FormsBook.Toolkit library and look for `TargetFrameworkProfile`. To disable Silverlight, you should change it to `Profile111`. (Or the same thing your other library has). Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @KaiBrummund Thank you, it worked! If you post you comment as an answer I will accept  it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017, Silverlight has been removed as an option.

You can edit the .csproj file of your FormsBook.Toolkit library and look for the Tag `<TargetFrameworkProfile>`. To disable Silverlight, you should change it to `Profile111` (or the same thing your other library has).

You can find a list of these profiles in [Stephen Cleary's Blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html).